# How to avoid "sendmsg()/writev() failed in logger" error in haproxy docker

Tags: docker, haproxy

I'm getting this error in the docker logs of my haproxy:

```
[ALERT] 135/235942 (8) : sendmsg()/writev() failed in logger #1: No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

My setup is described in the following question:
[HAProxy in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67554744/3118613)

Can anyone suggest how to fix that?

Also, how can I view/enable logs of actual accesses to the haproxy and routing activity to the different servers?

Thanks

Comment: I am having same issue. please let me know if you have answer

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log - if not, restart rsyslogd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Found out that running haproxy *chrooted*, the `/dev/log` was not available inside the chroot. Removing/commenting the following line made logging work for me:

```
global
#    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
```

Would have been nice if haproxy would open the log socket before going chroot.